# Unable to locate element of credit card number using selenium python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am working to enter info in the input field with using selenium with python.
The element I'm trying to access is

```
<input type="tel" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" class="number" data-braintree-name="number" name="credit-card-number" id="credit-card-number" maxlength="22" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" aria-describedby="field-description-number" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAfBJREFUWAntVk1OwkAUZkoDKza4Utm61iP0AqyIDXahN2BjwiHYGU+gizap4QDuegWN7lyCbMSlCQjU7yO0TOlAi6GwgJc0fT/fzPfmzet0crmD7HsFBAvQbrcrw+Gw5fu+AfOYvgylJ4TwCoVCs1ardYTruqfj8fgV5OUMSVVT93VdP9dAzpVvm5wJHZFbg2LQ2pEYOlZ/oiDvwNcsFoseY4PBwMCrhaeCJyKWZU37KOJcYdi27QdhcuuBIb073BvTNL8ln4NeeR6NRi/wxZKQcGurQs5oNhqLshzVTMBewW/LMU3TTNlO0ieTiStjYhUIyi6DAp0xbEdgTt+LE0aCKQw24U4llsCs4ZRJrYopB6RwqnpA1YQ5NGFZ1YQ41Z5S8IQQdP5laEBRJcD4Vj5DEsW2gE6s6g3d/YP/g+BDnT7GNi2qCjTwGd6riBzHaaCEd3Js01vwCPIbmWBRx1nwAN/1ov+/drgFWIlfKpVukyYihtgkXNp4mABK+1GtVr+SBhJDbBIubVw+Cd/TDgKO2DPiN3YUo6y/nDCNEIsqTKH1en2tcwA9FKEItyDi3aIh8Gl1sRrVnSDzNFDJT1bAy5xpOYGn5fP5JuL95ZjMIn1ya7j5dPGfv0A5eAnpZUY3n5jXcoec5J67D9q+VuAPM47D3XaSeL4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" aria-invalid="true">
```

I have tried 
Finding by Xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='credit-card-number']").send_keys(creditcardnumber)
```

Finding by Name

```
driver.find_element_by_name("credit-card-number").send_keys(creditcardnumber)
```

Finding by ID

```
driver.find_element_by_id('credit-card-number').send_keys(creditcardnumber)
```

I need help with locating the element for input.I get an error

```
Unable to locate the element
```

### Update

Here is the [URL](https://www.audiobooks.com/signup) for reference.

Comment: So what is the problem? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the question.
need help with locating the element because I get an error "Unable to locate the element "

Comment: Is there asynchronous script on the page that you need to `wait` or `sleep` until it loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to send a character sequence within an `<input>` field sems to be a **Credit Card Number** and historically *Credit Card Number* resides within `<iframes>`.

So if the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.audiobooks.com/signup")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-number']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='number' and @id='credit-card-number']"))).send_keys("1234567890987654")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot

[image: credit-card-number]

Comment: There's an iframe enclosing the CC input field on your example site. It has `id='braintree-hosted-field-number'`

Comment: I tried the above code, it didn't work.
replaced 

.click() 
with  
send_keys()

Comment: @TestedTester Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @TestedTester Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. 
Just for understanding was the previous answer not working because class='number' wasn't mentioned?

Comment: @TestedTester I am sorry, don't remember now. Perhaps tomorrow I can answer when I will be at my lab.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> Unable to locate the element

usually because element generated by javascript, use `WebDriverWait`

```
inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='credit-card-number']")
)
inputCC.send_keys(creditcardnumber)
```

other possibility is the element located in `iframe`

Comment: Error

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: