# Switching frames into an iframe doesn't allow me to see the credit card number

Tags: selenium, iframe

I have a site that embeds an iFrame with a sage Pay credit card section. I am not able to see anything within the iframe via Selenium. I have tried switching to the actual iframe (using index, web element and name) and then even trying to navigate to its iframe, but I am simply not able to see any of the html within the iframe itself using Selenium. I can see it within devTools. I assume Selenium cannot see it because it is secure? How can I get to the contents of this iframe?

Here is what i have tried
getContext().getDriver().switchTo().frame(getContext().getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='and-card-iframe']")).get(0)).findElements(By.xpath("//input"))

[credit card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj0WG.png)

Comment: btw, i have already tried the solution in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030701/unable-to-locate-element-of-credit-card-number-using-selenium-python

and that didn't help

Comment: Just in case anyone has the same issue, i found a solution.

 AjaxElementLocatorFactory ajaxElementLocatorFactory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(webDriver, 60);
    PageFactory.initElements(ajaxElementLocatorFactory, this);

Once this is done, you then can switch to the IFrame and then everything works