# How to click on element which contains a credit card number that changes each time with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, credit-card

I have a problem to find element on credit card payment form, which contains a number that changes each time, so please help me to find the way to do it.

This is the element:

```
<input id="adyen-checkout-encryptedCardNumber-1644589302666" data-fieldtype="encryptedCardNumber" type="text" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="24" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" aria-label="Champ du numéro de carte" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="adyen-checkout-encryptedCardNumber-1644589302666-ariaError" class="js-iframe-input input-field" data-type="gsf" style="display: block;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various locator strategies you can use (as per the DOM provided in the query):

All are xpaths

```
//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber']

//input[@type='text']

//input[@inputmode='numeric']

//input[@aria-label='Champ du numéro de carte']
```

Comment: I use this code but doesnt click
    def enter_cart_credit_card_number(self, credit_card_number):
        cart_credit_card_number_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        cart_credit_card_number_id.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber']"))).click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber']").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber']").send_keys(credit_card_number)

Comment: This works for me indeed, with the code that you provided in the query:

`cc = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber']")))
cc.clear()
cc.send_keys('5434234567788')`

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: I am sorry, but then need to inspect the website. is it possible to provide the website link?

Comment: It's an intern website

Answer (score 0):

This HTML...

```
<input id="adyen-checkout-encryptedCardNumber-1644589302666" data-fieldtype="encryptedCardNumber" type="text" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="24" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" aria-label="Champ du numéro de carte" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="adyen-checkout-encryptedCardNumber-1644589302666-ariaError" class="js-iframe-input input-field" data-type="gsf" style="display: block;">
```

...indicates a [Creditcard Number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54039805/7429447) field.

Generally *Creditcard Number* fields are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447). Hence to access the *Creditcard Number* field you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe_css")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber'][aria-label='Champ du numéro de carte']"))).send_keys("1234567890")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe_xpath")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber' and @aria-label='Champ du numéro de carte']"))).send_keys("1234567890")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to enter date in the credit card number field using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65149924/7429447)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847390/7429447)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @undetected Selenium for you response it was a frame problem so this is what i do and its works fine for me  :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='adyen-card-container']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/label/div/span/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedCardNumber']"))).send_keys("0000111122223333")
##switch parent frame
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='adyen-card-container']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/label/div/span/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedExpiryDate']"))).send_keys("0228")
##switch parent frame
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
        (By.XPATH,  "//*[@id='adyen-card-container']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/label/div/span/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-fieldtype='encryptedSecurityCode']"))).send_keys("123")
```